# Android - GPS provider does not work

Tags: android, gps

Why do I everytime get message "GPS is null!" after calling (by button) GetGps()? And GPS never is not showed, neither after long time, neitehr after the second calling GetGps():

Code is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B15F9QxsWXRqbkxOcFZ3OVNXUTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Put your code inside question. Mark corresponding lines. Help people who wants you help.

Answer (score 0):

My program is well. I was not within reach of gps signal.